# Is there a way to call Google Assistant using custom app name?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

My application name is quite general, so Assistant often opens a Web page instead of activating an Action.

Normally, Google Assistant uses the application name as a part of the calling phrase to verify which app to start. But according to my problem, it is better to provide an opportunity to declare the user's own custom word which can be used for calling phrase instead of the actual application name.

So that user can start an application and any Action with the phrase: "Hey Google, open CustomAppName"

Does anyone know to cope with this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you can refer [from](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature#example-queries) here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  There can only be one "invocation name" for an app, and that will apply to all users using that app.  There is no customization.